# Analysis on SQL sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below and want to perform analysis based on subqueries e.g.  sql

`select from Table1 where Value (Param.internal ) >   Value Param.external.`

```
Department,  Param,      Value
Dept1,      internal,     5
Dept1,      external,     6
Dept1,      others,       10
Dept2,      internal,     4
Dept2,      external,     3
Dept2,      others,       8
Dept3,      internal,     5
Dept3,      external,     5
Dept3,      others,       7
```

This didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE [Values] IN ( 
    SELECT [Value] 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE Param= 'internal' > 
    SELECT [Value] 
    FROM Table1 WHERE Param= 'external'
    )
```

Comment: What is your question? What code did you write and find to not give you the output you expected?

Comment: You need to pivot your Param col and then use where clause. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This is uncleare what you're asking.

Comment: This didn't work:  SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE [Values] IN (
    SELECT [Value] FROM Table1 WHERE Param= 'internal'
    >
    SELECT [Value] FROM Table1 WHERE Param= 'external')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This didn't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE [Values] IN (SELECT [Value] 
                   FROM Table1 
                   WHERE Param= 'internal' > SELECT [Value] FROM Table1 WHERE Param= 'external')
```

I think you are trying to find department the internal column is larger the external.

Try this:

```
select Department
    ,sum(case when Param = 'internal' then Value else 0 end) as Internal
    ,sum(case when Param = 'external' then Value else 0 end) as External
    ,sum(case when Param = 'others' then Value else 0 end) as Others
    --Added based on comment
    , (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Department) from Table1) as CtDistinctDept
    ,sum(Value) as DeptTotal
from table1
group by department
--optional
having sum(case when Param = 'internal' then Value else 0 end)
      > sum(case when Param = 'external' then Value else 0 end)
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I've added count(Distinct(Department)) as Count but the answer is always 1.   Is it possible to get a full count of all the Departments returned by the query?

Comment: @user3359706 . not sure how it helps but i added it. I also added a Total which I think you might be asking for.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would write the query with an EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE Param = 'internal'
AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM Table1 t2
 WHERE Param = 'external'
 AND t1.Department = t2.Department
 AND t1.value > t2.value)
```

So basically return all the rows where:

1. Param = internal AND
2. There is another row with the same department name where param = external and the external value is less than the internal one

According to your sample data above, department 2 would be returned.

Edit based on comment:
If you want to show all rows for the department, you just have to join the above back to the main table, like this:

```
SELECT main.*
FROM Table1 main
INNER JOIN
(SELECT t1.Department
 FROM Table1 t1
 WHERE Param = 'internal'
 AND EXISTS
 (SELECT 1
  FROM Table1 t2
  WHERE Param = 'external'
  AND t1.Department = t2.Department
  AND t1.value > t2.value) sub
ON main.Department = sub.Department
```

Comment: I like this method but it only shows 'internal' params in the report.  Is it possible to show all params when the conditions are met?

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks